# What series of hard SF novels is this riddle describing?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I [found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/59326/5373) the following riddle which describes a series of award-winning hard SF novels by a still-living British author:

> Born on the first soil, aiming for the next
>   Stolen as replacement, his life a lie
>   To be loved, serve but never die
>   Death came in a flash, lost mother
>   Hideous rictus, fear and darkness
>   Insanity lurking in the water
>   A mirror to his own madness
>   Four were in fact five
>   Then five were four again
>   To be the first, leave none alive
>   Now only war will reign
>   Burning sacrifice, deceptive bait
>   To live on the edge for a century wait
>   A ghost to be revealed, reborn on the second soil

Now technically this is a riddle, but it can also work as a story-ID question. This site has the SF story experts, so I'm sure one of you will recognise this series even from the slightly cryptic description.

**What hard SF series is being described here?**

Comment: Ooh this is a good one. I would have said the Forever War series by Joe Haldeman, but he's American. Hmmm....

Comment: I think this kind of question should be off topic.

Comment: @user14111 Well, you can always vote to close it and see if others agree, or even start a meta discussion about it. I realised it might be a bit scope-stretching, but on balance I thought it should be on-topic. We already accept questions like "I heard a story described [in another story | on a web forum | by my father]; based on the description, what story is it?"

Comment: *votes to migrate to Puzzling.SE* ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This a cryptic description of **Alastair Reynolds' Revelation Space** novels. More particularly it's describing Sky Haussmann, protagonist/antagonist of "Chasm City", but the last few lines refer to:

> his cameo appearance a century later in "Redemption Ark".

The first four lines:

Born on the first soil, aiming for the next

> Sky Haussmann is on a generation ship fleet heading for another planet.

Stolen as replacement, his life a lie

> Ostensibly Titus Haussman's son, it's later revealed that he was secretly adopted after the real son died.

To be loved, serve but never die

> He's ships crew and immortal.

Death came in a flash, lost mother

> One of the generation ships blew up, killing his mother.

Etc etc